# How to make an WordPress element sticky?

Tags: jquery, css, templates, comments

I'm trying to make an element sticky on my article.

This is the element- **Name**: `WP-Review`

```
<div Class=sticky-review>
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-review]"); ?>
</div>
```

I tried CSS- position: fixed; but that makes the element sticky for the whole site and appear even out of the template part on my article.

I use the element on my comments template. I want its appearance just like basic WordPress sidebar but for comments, not the post content. My Post content width is 100%. while comments width is 70% and the element is 30%.

I have no Idea if CSS or jQuery will do the trick and how? Can anyone Help me?

Comment: I don't understand how can this be an off topic question. I asked about a WordPress element and I'm not sure if CSS or jQuery can solve my problem. This site is probably not for beginners.

Comment: Actually there is nothing called `WP-Review` element in WordPress core. Most likely you are using a plugin for the related shortcode. Unfortunately, you don't know enough about WordPress to realize why it's not about WordPress. I suggest you to post this is StackOverflow. Although, even there you'll need to provide more information. All the best.